# QGIS layer text field bug - unable to categorize

Tags: qgis

[image] Hi I'm still learning how to use QGIS. I've tried to add a text field called 'name' to the 'edges' layer (see screenshot attached). The layer is created but then when I create a new line on my map, the window where I would usually fill in the name seems to have been corrupted (the word 'name' has been replaced by symbols). As a result, when I try to categorize under the symbology tab, none of my categories show up and I can't differentiate the different lines I've drawn. I've tried to create the layer twice with the same issue. I'm using QGIS 3.4 long term release. Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add more details. What is the format of your Layer ? How does the field name look like in attribute table ? Did you set any Attribute form widget ? do you have anu other field that you can edit ?

Comment: I've added some more screenshots. Field name in attribute table has also been replace with symbols. I haven't set an attribute form widget. No other fields added.

Comment: This look like an encoding problem (your is set to UTF-32LE) try to set it to UTF-8